# Cannot retrieve all request headers using PHP slim framework

Tags: php, rest, http, slim, slim-3

I'm using PHP slim framework for a personal project. For some reason, the PSR implementation of Request in Slim apparently is filtering some headers. I am trying to set a custom CSRF token and it is not available via $request->getHeaders(). Here's one example that shows the problem:

```
$app->get('/bar', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    echo "PHP's getallheaders() <br>";
    foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name: $value <br>";
    }
    echo "Slim's GetHeaders() <br>";
    foreach ($request->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            echo "$name: $value <br>";
        }
    }
});
```

I get this output:

```
PHP's getallheaders()
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
csrf_name: csrf56fc038c2f6eb
csrf_value: 4e077c04dadf22377da2aebc1a8caa78
Cookie: PHPSESSID=41016nbag70gi6shq4u2tg0aq1
Connection: keep-alive

Slim's GetHeaders()
Host: localhost
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: null
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_COOKIE: PHPSESSID=41016nbag70gi6shq4u2tg0aq1
HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
```

I am trying to understand why the custom headers:

```
csrf_name: csrf56fc038c2f6eb
csrf_value: 4e077c04dadf22377da2aebc1a8caa78
```

are being removed by Slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Slim, it is the webserver.

Even though header whose name contains underscore is valid by HTTP spec, both [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) and [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html) silently drop those headers for security reasons. In general you should use only use headers containing `a..zA..Z` and `-` characters.

With Apache you can still access header with underscore in their name using `getallheaders()` which is an alias to `apache_request_headers()`.

With Nginx you can enable headers with underscrore in their name with `underscores_in_headers on` setting.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know those details about HTTP servers. I found by trial and error so my first reaction was to think it was Slim the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the problem was that Slim does not like an underscore in a user-defined header. Once I changed csrf_name to csrfname it worked:

```
PHP's getallheaders()
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
csrfvalue: 4e077c04dadf22377da2aebc1a8caa78
csrfname: csrf56fc038c2f6eb
Cookie: PHPSESSID=5aom8b5q7ottorc9279q9sh4g1
Connection: keep-alive

Slim's GetHeaders()
Host: localhost
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: null
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_CSRFVALUE: 4e077c04dadf22377da2aebc1a8caa78
HTTP_CSRFNAME: csrf56fc038c2f6eb
HTTP_COOKIE: PHPSESSID=5aom8b5q7ottorc9279q9sh4g1
HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
```

So, don't forget, remove underscores!!

**EDIT** As explained by Mika Tuupola, the root cause is the HTTP server and not slim.